# Accuracy of the term "mother-in-law" in two cases

Tags: vocabulary

> Case 1: The wife of a child's father, but not the child's mother (i.e. second >marriage, or bastard child)
>
> Case 2: The mother of one's spouse

Based on what I've found online, "mother-in-law" is used for the second case.
What of the first?

Comment: Stepmother : http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stepmother

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *Nicholas Nickleby,* Dickens writes:

> “The fact is, I am not their father, Mr Squeers. I’m only their father-in->law” ... “You see, I have married the mother.”

So parent-in-law has been used for a non-parent who is married to a child's parent.

But *step-parent* has replaced this usage in current English.

Comment: This is technically correct, but the phrase "more common" is far too weak.  "Step-parent" is universally used in modern English for the spouse of a parent who is not also the child's parent.  "Parent-in-law" is exclusively reserved for the parent of a spouse in modern usage.  I can't upvote this unless you strengthen it.

Comment: @ChrisSunami You are right.

Answer (score 2):

The OED takes an interesting position on this. It accepts that the terms *mother-in-law* and *father-in-law* apply to the parents of a person's spouse. Of that there is no doubt. **However historically both terms have applied to what we now call *stepfather* or *stepmother***.

In the case of ***father-in-law*** the OED provides examples dating between 1552 and 1876 including by such writers as Charles Dickens and George Eliot. However the OED states clearly that it is now ***commonly regarded as a misuse of the term***.

But in the case of ***mother-in-law*** the sense meaning *stepmother* has far more recent examples, and the OED claims it as a ***regionalism***. It doesn't however state in which regions it might be found. Though the late-nineteenth and twentieth-century examples range from Devonshire, North Yorkshire, Jamaica, and Northern Ireland.

See below OED entries for the step-parent sense of ***father-in-law*** and ***mother-in-law***.

> **2. = stepfather n.   Now commonly regarded as a misuse.**
>
> 1552   R. Huloet Abcedarium Anglico Latinum   Father in lawe,
>   vitricus.
>
> 1597   Shakespeare Richard III v. v. 34   All comfort that the darke
>   night can afford, Be to thy person noble father in law.
>
> 1598   R. Grenewey tr. Tacitus Annales iii. vi. 72   A..band of
>   alliance..betwixt the father in lawe, and his wiues children.
>
> 1748   S. Richardson Clarissa IV. xxiii. 122   Nancy could not bear a
>   father-in-law.
>
> 1773   O. Goldsmith She stoops to Conquer i. 12   Father-in-law has
>   been calling me whelp, and hound.
>
> 1839   Dickens Nicholas Nickleby iv. 27,   I am not their father, Mr.
>   Squeers. I'm only their father-in-law.
>
> 1876   ‘G. Eliot’ Daniel Deronda IV. vii. lvi. 150,   I did not like
>   my father-in-law to come home.
>
> **2. = stepmother n. 1a. Now regional**.
>
> 1516   St. Bridget (Pynson) in J. H. Blunt Mirror our Lady (1873) p.
>   xlviii,   Hir moder in lawe.
>
> 1642   T. Fuller Holy State i. x. 26   If she becomes a mother in law,
>   there is no difference betwixt her carriage to her own and her second
>   husbands children.
>
> 1733   H. Fielding Miser iv. xiv. 65,   I know the Word,
>   Mother-in-law, has a terrible Sound, but perhaps I may make a better
>   than you imagine.
>
> 1751   Narr. Life J. Daniel i. 4   My father being..constantly abroad
>   till ten o'clock, my new mother-in-law spent most part of his absence
>   with me.
>
> 1787   J. Beattie Scoticisms 55   Mother-in-law..in Scot. and in Eng.
>   too..is often used improperly for step-mother.
>
> 1819   Shelley Cenci Pref. p. vii,   This daughter..at length plotted
>   with her mother-in-law and brother to murder their common tyrant.
>
> 1847   Thackeray Vanity Fair (1848) xiv. 119   Miss Sharp will be your
>   mother-in-law..that's what will happen.
>
> 1866   N. & Q. 24 Mar. 247/1   Mother-in-law,..this name is very
>   generally given to step-mothers in the..West Riding of Yorkshire.
>
> 1866   N. & Q. 21 Apr. 336/1   It is a very usual thing for the lower
>   orders in Devonshire to call a step-mother a mother-in-law.
>
> 1903   J. Wright Eng. Dial. Dict. IV. 172/2   [W.
>   Yorkshire]_Mother-in-law, a step-mother... Very common.
>
> 1956   in F. G. Cassidy & R. B. Le Page Dict. Jamaican Eng. (1980)
>   306/1   /mi maadanlaa, mi madarinlaa/, father's wife who is not her
>   mother.
>
> 1996   C. I. Macafee Conc. Ulster Dict. 228/2   Mother-in-law, a
>   step-mother.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I actually merely forgot the terms 'stepfather' and 'stepmother', but I've learned something new today.