# Definition of 'uncle-in-law'

Tags: meaning, word-usage, history, kinship-terms

I've been reading an old will and testament (Tudor era) and have encountered the usage of the term 'uncle-in-law'. My suspicion is that it would be rather odd (albeit not completely unreasonable) for this term to refer to the husband of his aunt, who would much more naturally be described merely as an uncle. It strikes me as much more likely that it refers to the uncle of his wife. I would like to confirm this if possible.

The OED [lists this term](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/uncle-in-law_n?tl=true&tab=factsheet) with a first recorded usage of 1561, though I'm unable to access the details. I would be grateful if anyone could provide more information on any 16th century (or at least early modern) examples of use, in particular with regards to which of the two aforementioned relations the term referred to.

Comment: in-law=by marriage.

Comment: @Lambie but the question is asking whether it is a marriage in the elder generation (husband of sibling of parent) or the younger generation (brother of parent of spouse) or even both (husband of sibling of parent of spouse).  My guess is that any of these is possible.

Comment: @Henry I think the 'both' case is much less likely, but yes, a priori I'd agree that either of the first two cases is possible.

Comment: This might be more suitable for law.stackexchange.com, given the context in which "uncle-in-law" appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a little more information on *uncle-in-law* in 16th century. I’ll leave it to you, though, to figure out who did what to whom to earn that designation . . .

The *OED*’s earliest attestation for *uncle-in-law* is:

> <sub>**1561**   All the premisses, this deponent knowis [to be]
> true, bie cause he is Vncle-in-lawe to [the sai]d Homfrey. —in F. J.
> Furnivall, *Child-marriages, Divorces, & Ratifications Diocese
> Chester* (1897) 3</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

You can [view the referenced sentence at HathiTrust](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hngedb&seq=112&q1=vncle&view=2up) in Furnivall’s 1897 publication for The Early English Text Society—filed under **Depositions taken in the Ecclesiastical Court of Chester, from Nov. 1561 to March 1565-6**—*I: Child-Marriages*. Here’s an image of the subject page:

[image: Vncle-in-lawe usage in 1561]

It all promises to be an interesting read; here’s a snippet from the “flyer” for the publication:

> This book is believd by the Editor to be the most light-giving and
> interesting volume ever publisht on the social life of the Diocese of
> Chester in 1561-6... It ranges... from... mansion-owning squires to
> the little alehouse-keepers, farmers and cobblers, the maids and the
> men... It gives us women tricking men, and more men tricking women. It
> contains quarrels and abuse of all kinds, exprest often in homely,
> racy words. It shows... one improper cleric amusingly illustrating a
> joke of Shakspere’s.

Comment: Aha. "The deponent had married his aunt." So an uncle-in-law is someone who became an uncle by marrying an aunt, which is the first definition from OED in my answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach — Yes, the deponent married Homfrey’s aunt, making the deponent Homfrey’s uncle-in-law.

Comment: I think I'll accept this, as though it's only one source, it still gives the most evidence on usage of the term in the Tudor period. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any sources except common usage. I believe the in-law is only used for relations on your spouse's side. That is the only marriage that matters in the in-law label. Other marriages like your uncle's, brother's or grandparent's don't get the in-law label. So your uncle and his wife would be simply introduced as your aunt and uncle. Your wife's uncle however would be introduced as your uncle-in-law.

Siblings are an exception as your brother's wife can be your sister-in-law (because you are her brother-in-law through her marriage to your brother). That can be confusing as sister-in laws are usually understood to be your spouse's siblings. So I would usually introduce her as my brother's wife.

Comment: In common usage, my siblings' spouses are my brothers-in-law and sister-in-law (as are my spouse's siblings).

Comment: Yes, that's the one exception.

Comment: It makes the sibling-in-law relationships reflexive: You're the brother-in-law of your sister-in-law. @Henry

Comment: It also works that way for child-in-law: Your daughter-in-law is the spouse of your child, not the child of your spouse (who is either your daughter or step-daughter).

Comment: No one ever said that English is consistent.

Comment: I would have thought you could make the same argument again: if my uncle-in-law is my spouse's uncle, then I am presumably his nephew-in-law even if not the nephew of his spouse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd tend to agree with you, though I do think there are some tricky subtleties here. A son-in-law would have always been the husband of one's daughter, never the son of one's wife (who would either be one's son or stepson). Contrastingly, a father-in-law would have always been the father of one's wife, never the husband of one's mother (who would either be one's father or stepfather).

Comment: @Henry that's just weird to me - I don't consider my brother's wife a sister-in-law however I am her brother-in-law because of her marriage to my brother

Comment: @DJ. Out of curiosity, common usage for you is in a Canadian context, I take it?

Comment: @Noldorin yes Canadian

Comment: Okay, cheers. Here in Britain I think usage is similar, in that older-generation in-laws are all through your spouse. I think the same would probably be true elsewhere and in the past, but let's see.

Comment: That may be true _now_, but the question refers to Tudor times. In the past, _[parent]-in-law_ sometimes meant _step-parent_. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284954/accuracy-of-the-term-mother-in-law-in-two-cases).

Comment: "common usage"? This hardly counts for anything given that the question is about 400 year old documents.

Comment: @KateBunting Good to know, thanks. And indeed, the document in question dates to 1558, so I'm loath to make many assumptions about usage back then.

Answer (score 3):

OED isn't really much help here. There are a number of possibilities, as you have surmised.

> The husband or male partner of one's aunt or (in recent use) of the sister of one's mother or father; (also) the uncle of one's spouse or partner.

I'm not sure why there is a difference between the "sister of a parent" and an "aunt".

The citation from 1561 is useful only if you know who "the deponent" is and how he is actually related to "Homfrey".

> All the premisses, this deponent knowis [to be] true, bie cause he is Vncle-in-lawe to [the sai]d Homfrey.

Another citation is from an Indian publication of 2012 which is even more confusing. An existing uncle-in-law appears to be related to future brothers and cousins.

> Behind me stood the very uncle-in-law who was my nominal supervisor in Madras, and alongside him were my future brothers and cousins.

Other citations are similar, showing that the term is used but not what it means.

Comment: Does the OED give example sentences with dates? If both definitions have examples from the 1500s, then that settles that both were possible in the 1500s.

Comment: Thank you for these examples. Good to have, even if the exact meaning isn't clear. What is the exact source of the 1561 usage, may I ask?

Comment: I'm not sure the OED will be interested, but I've submitted this as an antedating in any case! Beats the existing one by three years.

Answer (score 1):

Common usage is rarely relevant in legal documents past or present. Legal documents tend to be literal therefore I suggest an Uncle-in-law could be any legally related Uncle but not a blood related uncle thus A) a parent's brother by marriage or B) a spouse's parent's brother or C) a spouses parent's brother by marriage. The best clue could be in understanding the context of how this phrase was used based on the rest of the sentence or the document.

Comment: My experience is that terminology on family relationships is highly flexible, and more so the further you go into the past. A "cousin" can mean almost anything. I would make no assumptions about the precise relationship without further evidence.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'd tend to agree with you that it implies the lack of a blood relation. Beyond that, I'm still not sure... it could be any of those three cases you suggest, particularly A or B, I'd say. Unfortunately there's no real clue what the exact meaning is from other parts of the document or indeed from other sources.